# Find out if a for has not broken

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

I have a simple for loop inside a function.

```
void Func(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (/*for is not broken*/)
    {
    }
}
```

What should I write instead of: "/* for is not broken*/"?

I don't want to define i outside the loop.

I don't want to define another variable outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious answer is to perform your code inside the loop, and then break, which in your trivial example would just look like:

```
void Func(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        {
           /* other stuff */
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally this problem occurs when you want to do something else outside the loop if you *didn't* break, which normally means defining the loop variable outside the loop. This is a little messy, but if you put the loop in a function, and return true/false (I prefer an enum here, since I personally dislike true/false return values unless it's quite clear from the function name what they *really* mean).

```
void LoopFuncReturnTrueOnBreak(void)
{
    for( /* loop conditions */ )
    {
        // stuff
        if ( /* condition */ )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Func(void)
{
    if (LoopFuncReturnTrueOnBreak())
    {
        /* other stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I needed to do something if for didn't break. Your answer (using a function) does exactly what I need.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it gives you what you want, and also of course if you actually needed something to happen when the loop didn't break, you should probably have put that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, without an additional variable, because there is no variable in the scope of if-statement in your code that you could test.

Answer (score 4):

I find your constraints very strange:

- I don't want to define i outside the loop.
- I don't want to define another variable outside the loop.

Any reason for this? It is normal to use a variable for this. Code is about readability, not trying to achieve the least lines of code.

But the only thing you can do without using an extra variable, is to handle it in the for loop. When you are about to break.

```
void Func(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        if (some_condition)
        {
            HandleBreakScenario();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason: I am using this pattern inside a complicated function repeatedly and I try to prevent adding more variables to my scope in function.

Comment: Your answer is right for broken for, Actually I needed to do something for not broken for (Sorry, my mistake in question, I edited it.).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use a variable:

```
bool didBreak = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    didBreak = true;
    break;
}
if (didBreak)
{
}
```

Trying to avoid this simple solution for the obscure reasons you mentioned just makes your life harder.